Fast swap pricing
Let's say I want to price a given unconventional swap as quick as possible (for ex. a 7.5y swap). The way I do it is I get the swap rate, sofr future price from different maket, construct my sofr curve and price the swap. The problem is that while I am constructing my sofr curve and price the swap, the market data can change. So how do you take into account that the market data can tick while pricing the swap? MM needs to take this into account to not get picked off, so wondering how this problem was solved by MM.

What is MM? How do you practically construct that curve? You are hopefully using some code that can be rerun with new market inputs.

I don't undertsand the question. It's all OTC and a market maker will set the price, so it does not tick unless you want it to. Also, a swap like that prices instantaneously, even on BBG.

Yes, you can assume that other people behind the scenes are constantly updating the curve(s) and all the info is conveniently displayed for you on the screen either in Bloomberg or some even fancier inhouse system.

@AKdemy The ATS desk in banks need to price quickly the RFQ they get. And you can find indicative quote for swaps to buid the curve. One way to do it might be to build in parallel different curve to get the delta of the swap for different pillars, but i am not sure

@nbbo2 yes exactly

maybe @Attack68 has an idea?
